# Regular expression to match OpenCart url format

Tags: regex, expression, opencart

I need a regular expression to match this URL to enable URL rewriting.

http://www.somewhere.com/index.php?route=common/home

This is an OpenCart website.

UPDATE:

I am trying to use the regular expression to perform URL Rewriting on IIS7. The first part of the URL doesn't need exact domain name matching but I need the to get a resulting URL as follows

http://www.somewhere.com/common/home

Comment: This expression does not match the initial URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't specify the language in which you're doing this (protip: not all regexp implementations have the same rules) so I'm solving it in python:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '([^/]+)//([^/]+)/index\.php\?route=([^ ]+)'
>>> repl = '\\1//\\2/\\3'
>>> url = 'http://www.somewhere.com/index.php?route=common/home'
>>> re.sub(pattern, repl, url)
'http://www.somewhere.com/common/home'
```

Comment: I am using it to perform URL rewriting in IIS7+. http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: ok I don't use IIS but according to this: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/ the previous pattern should work, but use `{R:1}//{R:2}/{R:3}` as the replacement

Comment: Yes your regex works and I am using that above url reconstruction pattern, however I cannot seem to get match. I must be missing something with the rewrite module

Comment: I will keep trying however you have answered my question so thanks v. much!

Answer (score 0):

The url rewrite gets the url after your domain and the initial / and passes it to index.php via GET using the *route* parameter, so

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/common/home
```

becomes

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?_route_=common/home
```

The _route_ is used by the url rewriting controller to work out the correct page/route to use. Note that to reverse the process (create the urls) You just need to enable the url rewriting on the settings page to enable them

That said, url rewriting by default only works for products, categories, manufacturers and information pages - so you won't be able to do that for the common/home route. There are modules out there however that will do that, and even allow you to customise the urls further such as my Uber SEO module, though that changes more than just basic urls

Comment: Thanks for this Jay. You touch on what I am looking for when you said rewriting the URLs that are not products, categories, manufactures and information pages. This is exactly what I am looking for as I want the entire site to use SEO friendly URLs.

Comment: Please provide a direct link to you Uber SEO module Jay. **UPDATE** [link](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3550&filter_search=seo%20url&sort=e.date_modified&order=DESC). Does this module work with Windows and IIS7

Comment: I was worried about the VQMOD requirement - so to answer my own question there doesn't seem to be any reason why it wouldn't work on Windows. I will try this component and hope it does the trick. I am still puzzled why my rewrite rule doesn't work however.

Comment: Before you purchase my mod, have you checked that you can rewrite products etc normally now in OpenCart with the current SEO url file? If not, be sure to do so, since if that isn't working, you will need to fix that before getting this. Also note the difference in the rewritten product, category, manufacturer and info page links on my mod, they differ greatly from the default, and something for you to take into consideration

Comment: I have had a look at the module. Was it necessary to rewrite the products, etc urls from the standard that opencart has? It would be good to leave those as they are and then rewrite only the ones that follow the format index.php?_route_=?/?

Comment: Well the rewrite for the other routes was actually second priority with the module when I wrote it. i've been meaning to have something similar for just regular urls, but it does make it tricky in a way as the standard urls aren't all that reliable